# Cannot insert data to mysql table using INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, wamp

In WAMP and in phpMyadmin I created a database called PROJECT with this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I am trying to test the following code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect ("localhost","******","");
mysql_select_db("project",$con);
@$a=$_POST['txt1'];
@$b=$_POST['txt2'];
if(@$_POST['inser'])
{
 $s="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$a','$b')";
echo "Your Data Inserted";
 mysql_query ($s);
}
$con=mysql_connect ("localhost","******","");
mysql_select_db ("project",$con);
if(@$_POST ['sel'])
{
echo $ins=mysql_query ("select * from users");
echo "<table bgcolor=skyblue border='2'>
<tr>
<th colspan=4>Display details</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($ins))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo  "<th>".$row ['id']."</th>";
echo  "<th>".$row ['username']."</th>";
echo  "<th>". $row ['password']. "</th>";

echo "</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>"
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="pink">
<table bgcolor="skyblue" border="2">
<form method="post">
<tr>
<td colspan=2 align="center">Details</td>
</tr>
<td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="txt1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td><td><input type="text" name="txt2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="inser" value="Insert"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="sel" value="Select"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I insert manually username and password in the database and click the Select button then I have the record. When I try to insert a record using the INSERT INTO above it is impossible to add the record. I have the message YOUR DATA INSERTED but there is no record in the database. I tried it without the field ID and it works perfect. I tried it also without AUTO INCREMENT but without results. So what is the problem with the ID?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
    if(isset($_POST['inser']))
    { 
    $s="INSERT INTO users (`username` , `password` )VALUES ('$a','$b')";
       mysql_query($s);
    echo "Your Data Inserted";
```

Answer (score 0):

$s="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','".$a."','".$b."')";

You have to insert . in the query for it to work. Try it like this.

Comment: ehm, are you shure? i dont think so

Comment: @steven I just edited my answer adding the " quotes after the '  quotes. Replace your existing your existing statment with this one and check it.

Comment: i dont know, it is not my question but i think @echo_Me is closer to the fix. The Version without the dots is the nearly the same as yours. if one version works the other should work, too because of the outer double quotes.

Comment: As far as I know in php variable should be outside of the comment. Therefore you should use the ' " . $ A . " ' rule

Answer (score 0):

```
$s="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$a','$b')";
```

should be something like:

```
$s="INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$a','$b')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try a safer method, just to make sure you insert ONLY the data you want to be inserted. For example:

```
$test=mysql_query("insert into user(username,password) values('$a','$b')");
```

then check if you got any errors

```
if(!$test || mysql_error())
     echo "Error";
else
     echo "Inserted";
```

**Note:** note that the **id** doesn't appear because it is auto-increment, and since is auto-incremented you don't and shouldn't insert values otherwise you will face an error.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that if you do like you did (`values('','$a','$b')`) it's actually unnecessary and not sure at the moment but I think it does give an error since you are inserting ''==null=='0' into the field.